# What is wrong on connection string

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to connect database.sdf on same director. Using following code but gives me connection error. What I am doing wrong. Please help me.

```
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim con As SqlCeConnection
    Dim command As SqlCeCommand
    connstring = "Persist Security Info = False; Data Source = '.\database.sdf', Password = 'pswrd', File Mode = 'shared read'"
    con = New SqlCeConnection
    con.Open()
    command = New SqlCeCommand("select * from users where Name=? and Password=?", con)
```

Comment: You might share this connection error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing some code... or maybe that's the problem, you never bind your SqlCeConnection to connstring

```
Dim con As SqlCeConnection
Dim command As SqlCeCommand
con = New SqlCeConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=.\database.sdf;Password=pswrd;File Mode=shared read")
con.Open()
command = New SqlCeCommand("select * from users where Name=? and Password=?", con)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the single quotes (`'`) in the different parts of the connection string, and you should be using a semi-colon (`;`) to separate the different values.

```
"Persist Security Info = False; Data Source = .\database.sdf; Password = pswrd; File Mode = shared read;"
```

Apart from that, you do not appear to be *using* the connection string in your code. You should be using it to open the connection:

```
con = New SqlCeConnection(connstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) for great connection string assitance.

It looks like your line:

> connstring = "Persist Security Info = False; Data Source = '.\database.sdf', Password = 'pswrd', File Mode = 'shared read'"

is using both "," and ";" to separate the parameters. Update then all to use ";"

Comment: Try this link to the ConnectionStrings website. I think it'll get you closer to the information you want. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce